# Создание записей с различным набором атрибутов

Tags: sql, база-данных, ms-access

Имеется 4 типа компаний(дистрибьютер, оптовик, мелкий оптовик, сети), с которыми мы работаем, но набор атрибутов между дистрибьютером, оптовиком, и мелким оптовиком отличается от сетей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал реализовать данную схему подобным образом[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

расчет был на то, что в форме свяжу две таблицы и буду работать со всеми компаниями(т.к. выборку необходимо будет делать по всем компаниям) (счетчик id_сети поставил со 100000, чтобы избежать конфликта id_сети и id_компании)
но, когда, уже в готовой схеме, попробовал вставить запись в таблицу "компания_продукт"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
вылетела ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как я понял один и тот же id должен существовать в обоих таблицах и мой способ реализации в корне не верен. Подскажите пожалуйста способ с помощью которого можно реализовать данную схему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создается таблица с названием типа "Контрагент", туда идут общие для компаний и сетей поля, вроде названия и краткого названия, типа компании, создаем таблицы с дополнительными реквизитами для каждого типа компании, кардиналити будет один к одному. Работаем с основной таблицей, подтягиваем детали по мере надобности.